# send email without user interaction in android geting auth error

Tags: java, android, gmail, jakarta-mail

Hi every one following code for i worte send email in android but i am geting auth error kaindly help me to solve this

```
    private void sendMail(String email, String subject, String messageBody,File file) {
        Session session = createSessionObject();
//        new UpdateTask().execute();
        try {
            Message message = createMessage(email, subject, messageBody, session,file);

            new UpdateTask().execute(message);

        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, Session session,File file) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("XXXXXXXX@gmail.com", "Sound Check"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, email));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(messageBody);
        /**
         * Attach a file in mail 
         */
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        return message;
    }

    private Session createSessionObject() {
           Properties props = new Properties();   
           props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
           props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");   
           props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
           props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
           props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        return Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "*********");
            }
        });
    }
}
class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Message,String,String> {



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Message... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Message message = params[0];
         try {

                Transport.send(message);

            } catch (AddressException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Getting Error like this:

```
08-14 12:09:23.365: W/System.err(30695): javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
08-14 12:09:23.365: W/System.err(30695):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
08-14 12:09:23.365: W/System.err(30695):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
08-14 12:09:23.365: W/System.err(30695):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
08-14 12:09:23.365: W/System.err(30695):    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
08-14 12:09:23.365: W/System.err(30695):    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
08-14 12:09:23.365: W/System.err(30695):    at com.example.callrecoder.UpdateTask.doInBackground(RecordService.java:384)
```

same timei get mail like bellow :

sub : Sign-in attempt prevented

mail :

Hi name 
 some one just try to sign in your google account "mailid " form app that doesn't meet modern security standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the most common things for AuthenticationFailedException in JavaMail

1. First, fix these [common mistakes.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)
2. Turn on [Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see if the protocol trace gives
   any more clues about what's wrong.
3. You may need to [enable access for less secure apps.](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) This error may be from google security... This can be Resolved by Enabling Less Secure "TURN ON"

After these all steps, still your facing problem ? I am here to help you !!

Comment: happy to help :) accept my answer if it works for you @K.Muthu

Comment: You should fix common mistakes as well.  Really.  It will make your program simpler and more correct.